# how to align bottom between two view and align top to parent at the same time?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to align bottom between two view and align them to the top of parent. It fails when either of them is taller than the other one. Seems like `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/rightText"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` contradict each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/leftText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

actual:
[image]

expect:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make your constraint layout warpcontent. And then your text use bottom to parent. U think, it should do the trick

Comment: @JackyTsang , the answers didn't solve your problem? I can see you edited my answer without any feedback

Comment: @DavidIbrahim no. it does not work. your code just removed `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`. It has problem when `leftText` is taller than `rightText`

Comment: @JackyTsang
did you add it to android studio and visualized it?  Cuz it works here, of course, it will remove that line from one of the views because let's say for example we have viewA and viewB ...
viewA is connected to viewB and ViewB is connected to the top of parent ..... no need to directly connect viewA to parentTop, did actually you try to select the views and right-click align bottom?

Comment: @TeddySmith tried. it does not work even the container is using `wrapcontent`. I can't use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` because the attribute is already used.

Comment: @DavidIbrahim of course I tried. I visualize it on android studio preview. I saw that they are not aligned to bottom when leftText is taller than rightText using your code

Comment: @JackyTsang you are totally right, I modified my answer and explained it, I think it works ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the top of the two views to parent and connect the bottom of each of the two views to each other and then make the vertical bias in the two texts equal to one

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:text="Header asd da asd sda ads dsa dsa ads sda dsa das dsa das dsa dsda s dssdanksadasdjadsasbdjadskbjsdkbajdsbjasdkbjkadsbjkadsbjkasdbjkaskbjasdbjkasdbjkasdbjkasdbjkasdkbjasbjkasdkbjasdbjkasdbjkHeader Header Header Header Header Header Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/leftText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:text="RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `verticalBias` attribute to set the right header at the bottom otherwise, it will be at the centre of the parent's top and left's bottom.
Set `verticalBias` = 0 (to align with top) or 1 (to align with bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `wrap_content` `ConstraintLayout` and align both views to bottom of parent. This is one way to it

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightText"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
    tools:text="RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader RightHeader" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```